# Modern Multilingual pages in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, multilingual, spo

I have case

1. PROD site had some pages and their translations created.
2. We migrated the pages (using Sharegate) to the QA site.
3. The translation connection is lost (on the QA site) and new translation pages need to be created.

Does anyone know how to reconnect the translated pages to their originals?
We are using modern SPO multilingual features.

Comment: How did you create the translations?
Using the variations features?

Comment: Nope, using the translation feature in modern experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I managed to find a way of achieving it.
Below process needs to be followed:

1. Using pnp Export original page.

   ```
    $PageName =  "Education-Grant.aspx"
    $TempFile = "C:\Education-Grant.xml"
    Export-PnPClientSidePage -Force -Identity $PageName -Out $TempFile
   ```
2. Using pnp Export the translation (ie french)

   ```
    $PageName =  "fr/Education-Grant.aspx"
    $TempFile = "C:\FR_Education-Grant.xml"
    Export-PnPClientSidePage -Force -Identity $PageName -Out $TempFile
   ```
3. Update the original page export to include French page as translation.
   Add following properties to original page:

   ```
   PageName="Air-Transport.aspx" LCID="1033" CreateTranslations="false"
   ```

   Add pnp:Translations node and copy into it whole pnp:ClientSidePage node from French export. .

   Add LCID="1036" to the copied page.
4. Delete both original and french from the source site.
5. Apply modified pnp template.

Now the original page and its translation are reunited.

some references:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2olxC99UBQ&ab_channel=Microsoft365Community
  https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/blob/master/OfficeDevPnP.ProvisioningSchema/ProvisioningSchema-2021-03.xsd